# Type issues when returning currentUser with AngularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm still new to Typescript, Angular and to Firebase Auth. I'm alreay able to sign a user in and I can see that AngularFire automatically stores the info in localStorage (as configured). However, when trying to do `auth.currentUser`, I'm running into typing problems left and right.

This is my `authentication.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth'
import { GoogleAuthProvider, User } from '@angular/fire/auth';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  currentUserInfo?: UserInfo
  constructor(
    private auth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.currentUserInfo = {
          email: user.email
        }
      }
    })

  }

  getCurrentUser(): User {
    return this.auth.currentUser
  }

  signInWithGoogle(): Observable<unknown> {
    return from(this.auth.signInWithPopup(new GoogleAuthProvider()))
  }

  // email signin
  signIn(params: SignIn): Observable<unknown> {
    return from(this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      params.email, params.password
    ))
  }
}

type SignIn = {
  email: string,
  password: string
}

type UserInfo = {
  email: string
}
```

(As you can see, I'm also using observables of type `unknown` on the signin functions due to not really understanding which types are to use, so any suggestions on this are appreciated).

Below is the error I get in `getCurrentUser(): User`:

```
Type 'Promise<User | null>' is missing the following properties from type 'User': emailVerified, isAnonymous, metadata, providerData, and 13 more.ts(2740)
```

I'm also having problems in when trying to get info from the `user` parameter in `this.auth.onAuthStateChanged`. Here's the error:

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Does this mean I need to change the email in the `UserInfo` type to be `string | null`?

---

@Alexander Thanks so much for the suggestion. As for returning a promise, would it be something like this?

```
  async getCurrentUser(): Promise<User | null> {
    return await this.auth.currentUser
  }
```

This is giving me another, weirder type error:

```
Type 'firebase.default.User' is not assignable to type 'import(".../node_modules/@angular/fire/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-public").User'.
```

Comment: Add null checks.

Comment: From the first error i see that currentuser is returning a promise of User or null and you are looking for a user :) . what you can do
1. add await before this.auth.currentUser and chek  for null and return user 
```
const user: User | null = await this.auth.currentUser;
if( user === null ) throw an error 
return user 
```

Comment: Or you can return the promise or wrap it into an observable an subscribe. depending on the context and wheter you need the user from an async context or sync one.

Comment: Hey @Alexander, thank you so much for the response. `auth.currentUser` does indeed return a promise of `User | null`, but I'm getting another type error.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message ?

Comment: @Alexander I added it to the question